# CKEditor - Use Bootstrap js/css + Custom css inside ckeditor preview

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I would like to use bootstrap js/css **AND** a custom css file in ckeditor preview.
So, for example, if I write this code in ckeditor source code view...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color: red;">
    <p>First column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color: green;">
    <p>Second column</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

... I should see in ckeditor preview two 50% width columns (one red and one green).

I've found out that you can add css files to ckeditor with `contentsCss` or `addContentsCss` config (see ckeditor documentation for explanation), but what about bootstrap js files? How can I add js files to ckeditor preview?

I already know that (in order to allow class/styles tags) I need to configure ACF. For now I just used a quick fix to disable ACF completely:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {allowedContent: true} );
```

***Context:***
*My admin and frontend themes are different (both bootstrap-based, but different) and I use "CKEditor classic editing" or "framed editing", which means the editor creates a temporary  element for itself.

**Basically...It's the default/standard ckeditor implementation (version 4.4.7).***

**!!!!EDIT!!!!
My solution:**

```
/*Javascript files appear to be NOT necessary (if your page is bootstrap-based)  
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js','https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'] );  
*/
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss  = ['https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css','mycustom.css'];
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {allowedContent: true});
```

If you come up with a better solution, let me know.
 In the meantime, if you find this question useful please vote up to improve its visibility.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [`contentPreview`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-contentPreview) event which allows manipulation of preview HTML, like

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    on: {
        contentPreview: function( evt ) {
            evt.data.dataValue = '<b style="color: red; font-size: 10em">B</b>';
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can this help me apply bootstrap css and js to the preview content?(responsive behaviour, grid system, helper classes etc etc)

Comment: I updated the question with my solution... what do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

I think CKEditor [Bootstrap Utils](http://doksoft.com/soft/ckeditor-bootstrap/index.html) will help you. It allows you to include (attach) Bootstrap's styles to your CKEditor document (preview) area automatically due to this bundle has Bootstrap Include CSS/JS add-in inside it.

[image]